# Buscar Registros que não constam em outra tabela

Tags: sql, sql-server

Bom dia..

Tenho a tabela `[BCT_PESSOA]` com PK `[ID_PESSOA]` esta tabela tem relacionamento com a tabela `[BCS_USUARIO]` com a coluna `[ID_PESSOA]`

Gostaria de retornar todos os registros ta tabela `[BCT_PESSOA]` que os `[ID_PESSOA]` não existem na tabela `[BCS_USUARIO]`.

Comment: Em termos de teoria dos conjuntos, o que solicita é `C = A - B`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM BCT_PESSOA p
inner join BCT_PESSOATIPO pt on pt.ID_PESSOA = p.ID_PESSOA
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM BCS_USUARIO u WHERE p.ID_PESSOA = u.ID_PESSOA)
and pt.ST_TIPO = 'FUN'
```

creio que isso resolva

Comment: Em termos de teoria dos conjuntos, o que solicita é `C = A - B`. Há algumas formas de implementar em SQL, sendo que o uso de `WHERE not exists()` é uma delas.

Answer (score 2):

Segue um exemplo para a consulta.

```
   Select a.*
     from BCT_PESSOA a
left join BCS_USUARIO b on a.ID_PESSOA = b.ID_PESSOA
    where b.ID_PESSOA is null
```

Comment: Existem algumas formas de se chegar ao resultado, mas na minha opinião sua forma é a mais elegante. Usar um NOT EXISTS me parece verboso demais e polui o SQL.